# Why align-items-center does not work in Bootstrap4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

[How the stuff works in answered question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2L6.png)

[How the stuff works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N1fE.png)

Ok, so I'm using Bootstrap4 and I'm trying to vertically center the main container. And for some reason that doesn't work :/

[Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H53RZ.png)

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            debug
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thats not dublicate and not answered :|. The stuff in the answer doesnt work in my code. That's the problem. I tried every option in Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap 4

Comment: It *is* a duplicate. If you read the answer you'll see that it's not working because **the parent of the item you're trying to center doesn't have a defined height**. It just needs to have a defined height and then it works! https://www.codeply.com/go/kWTlZofg0Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you this [documentation about vartical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).
You should understand, that you need some elements, like a picture, for to see some difference. Or you wanna get smthing another? Draw your expected output.

Also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

My working example needs `white page`, because it was also not working as your page. The problem is in predefined project stuff. Find yours which doesn't allows you use this solution

```
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1 class="display-4">Jumbotron</h1>
                <p class="lead">This is a simple centered hero unit.</p>
                <p class="lead">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}  
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to make it with Bootstrap and not regular CSS. Like here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment

Comment: @TheQxiz, there to much info about this question. In my case I misunderstood you and thought that you need just to center text. You've got the link, if you'll meet some unusual case you can ask again

Comment: @TheQxiz, I have the same issue) searching for solution.

Comment: I have the link, code and other stuff but thats still not working for me xD I edited the question so you can see how the stuff works for everyone and how for me.

Comment: For me it works in the same way as yours)

Comment: I already tried to use that style thing. Thats the code for fine working jumbotron https://www.codeply.com/go/BumdFnmLuk

Comment: I did it. It works for me. Just create a new page, without any stuff. I think you have some kind of `css` links defined before your page. You should find the one which destroy suggested stuff.

Comment: Ohhh.. finally, thanks.

Comment: @TheQxiz, you're welcome) it was funny, because I've got the same issue in my project dir, after that I tried to do it on `white page`